# External 8MHz Oscillator not working for STM32F405RGT6 custom Hardware

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, oscillator, crystal

I am using custom-designed hardware for STM32F405RGT6. I need to put the chip in DFU mode to perform a DFU firmware upgrade. I am able to flash the chip via the STLINK, which indicates that the chip is functional. I have connected the Boot0 pin to Vdd. I am connecting the board to the PC via a USB cable whose DM, DP, and GND are connected to PA11 (DM), PA12(DP), and GND of chip respectively. The board is not detected on PC and doesn't show up on the device manager irrespective of BOOT0 status. As per my understanding, the USB needs HSE to function correctly as per AN2606.

[image: App Note]

I checked the waveform with an oscilloscope on both the terminals of the crystal and all I get is DC 1.8~1.75V on both pins (which means the oscillator isn't working). I also checked the waveform on the oscillator on the discovery kit from STM where I can clearly see an 8MHz 1.8V Vpp waveform. I am using the same oscillator as on the STM discovery kit and the resistor values are also the same.

Crystal Oscillator Troubleshooting Guide https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN3208.pdf

USB DFU Protocol (Pg 6) https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00264379-usb-dfu-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf

STM32 microcontroller system memory boot mode (Pg 110) https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf

I need your help to get the external crystal working as I believe it is the reason why my board isn't detecting on a PC.

Thank you.

Edit 1: Adding oscillator schematic for reference. Component Y1 is the crystal oscillator.
[image: Oscillator Schematic]

Comment: So does the crystal oscillate if you run the program loaded with ST-Link?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Well, should it? Have you turned the crystal oscillator on in your program? If not, it will not oscillate. Please post the schematics.

Comment: @Justme Uploaded the snapshot of the schematic.

Comment: At least schematic-wise it looks OK. But the crystal type is missing, so it is impossible to say if it will work.

Comment: @Justme previously I used ABLS-8.000MHZ-B2-T crystal, but later I desoldered one from the stm32 discovery kit and soldered it onto my board. The crystal from the discovery kit has the marking "JFVNY 8.0000". Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120777/discussion-between-niranjan-tarle-and-justme).